# How do I restart R in linux using a line of code?

Tags: r, linux

I need to restart an R session running in linux using a line of code. When the R session restarts I need it to load an existing R script and for the new R session to be clear of previously loaded packages, variables etc.

I've managed to make this work from within an R terminal in Windows using the following code:

```
library(startup)
restart(args = c('source("existing_code.R")'))
```

However when the same code runs in a Linux environment I get the following error:

> sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

> sh: -c: line 0: `'/opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/bin/exec/R' source("
> existing_code.R")'

Comment: Are you searching for `.rs.restartR()` ? Execute within the R console.

Comment: .rs.restartR() only works within RStudio